# Is possible to a sheet from 1 workbook to another with python(including values,styles and formating)?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I need to copy over 1 sheet to another workbook, ive done the values but I can not do the style
this is what I have so far but it does not copy

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter 
from copy import copy 
source_wb = load_workbook('headerRaw.xlsx') 
source_ws = source_wb.active 
dest_wb = load_workbook('demo.xlsx') 
dest_ws = dest_wb.create_sheet('Copied Sheet') 
for merge_range in source_ws.merged_cells.ranges:
    dest_ws.merge_cells(str(merge_range)) 
    for row in source_ws.iter_rows(): 
        for cell in row: # Skip over merged cells if isinstance(cell, MergedCell): 
            continue 
        new_cell = dest_ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column, value=cell.value) 
        if cell.has_style: 
            new_cell.font = copy(cell.font) 
            new_cell.border = copy(cell.border) 
            new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill) 
            new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format) 
            new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection) 
            new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment) 
dest_wb.save('demo.xlsx')
```

Comment: Your implementation of the duplication code doesn't make a lot of sense; Only does something if there is merged cells in the Sheet. Then has a loop that rejects all cells `for cell in row:` `continue` What is the purpose of this loop it isn't what the comment states? Therefore the code would copy just the last column of data. The reason being this is the last cell rejected in the row after the continue loop and before moving on to the 'copy' section in the iteration. I assume that is not what is desired.